# show all rows from left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT IF(viaturas.transportador IS NULL,
       'Sem transportador', viaturas.transportador) AS transportador,
       SUM(IFNULL(retorno_euro,0))- SUM(IFNULL(devolucao_euro,0)) AS total_euro,
       SUM(IFNULL(retorno_ddf,0))- SUM(IFNULL(devolucao_ddf,0)) AS total_ddf,
       SUM(IFNULL(retorno_vadias_plast,0))- SUM(IFNULL(devolucao_vadias_plast,0)) AS total_plast
FROM transportes.transportation_order
    LEFT JOIN transportes.viaturas ON viaturas.viatura=transportation_order.viatura
WHERE estado NOT IN ('cancelado', 'eliminado')
  AND servico IN ('Distribuição', 'Devolução', 'Re-Entrega')
  AND DATA >= '2016-08-08'
GROUP BY LOWER(transportador);
```

but only shows the result from matched rows.
How can i show all "tranportador" rows even when there is no match between the tables?

Comment: Add table definitions. (And qualify columns, i.e. tablename.columnname (just like viaturas.transportador.)

Answer (score 1):

When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table conditions in the `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` behavior. (When in the `WHERE` clause, you'll get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)

```
SELECT IF(viaturas.transportador IS NULL,
       'Sem transportador', viaturas.transportador) AS transportador,
       SUM(IFNULL(retorno_euro,0))- SUM(IFNULL(devolucao_euro,0)) AS total_euro,
       SUM(IFNULL(retorno_ddf,0))- SUM(IFNULL(devolucao_ddf,0)) AS total_ddf,
       SUM(IFNULL(retorno_vadias_plast,0))- SUM(IFNULL(devolucao_vadias_plast,0)) AS total_plast
FROM transportes.transportation_order
    LEFT JOIN transportes.viaturas ON viaturas.viatura=transportation_order.viatura
  AND estado NOT IN ('cancelado', 'eliminado')
  AND servico IN ('Distribuição', 'Devolução', 'Re-Entrega')
  AND DATA >= '2016-08-08'
GROUP BY LOWER(transportador);
```

Comment: This query has it is doesn't show all the rows i want, and put all the results on the 'Sem transportador' row.
If i remove the conditions after the left join it shows the rows i want but i need that conditions on my query

Comment: Edit your question; 1) Add table definitions. 2) Add sample table data. ) Show us the current query's result (using the sample data.) 4) Show us the expected result.